# Getting and editing gradient parameters in Caffe

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

Is it possible to get the gradients with respect to each layer in Caffe in CNNs, edit them and again apply the new gradients in the training process? If possible, using pycaffe interface.

For example in TensorFlow, it could be done by means of functions:

```
given_optimizer.compute_gradients(total_loss)
given_optimizer.apply_gradients(grads)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "apply the new gradients in the training process", but you can access the gradients in the pycaffe interface:

```
import caffe
net = caffe.Net('/path/to/net.prototxt', '/path/to/weights.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
# provide inputs to the net, do a pass so that meaningful data/gradients propagate to all the layers
net.forward_backward_all()

# once data/gradients are updated, you can access them
net.blobs['blob_name'].diff  # access the gradient of blob 'blob_name'
net.layers[5].blobs[0].diff  # access the gradient of the first parameter blob of the 6th layer
```

To map between layer names and layer indices, you can use this code:

```
list(net._layer_names).index('layer_name')
```

This will return the index of layer `'layer_name'`.

Comment: By "applying gradients", I mean modifying the gradients which, on the other hand, later perform the weighs update in a given iteration during the training process.

Comment: @cerebrou you can modify the `.diff` part of the different blobs of the net, but I'm not sure caffe allows you to modify the gradients *before* they are used for weight updates. You can use the pycaffe interface to directly modify the weights, though...

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but after modification of the gradient, there does not seem to be a straighfoward way to make an update to the weights.

Comment: @cerebrou I never got to dig in that part of the code. But AFAIK, there is no simple way of tweaking the gradients and then tell caffe to update the weights accordingly. On the other hand, you do have a direct access to the parameters, so why not updating them directly?

Comment: This actually will suffice. Great idea.